# Placing search bar in navigation bar

Tags: html, css

[My current scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6nwL.png)

Hello,
I want to place a search bar inside a navigation bar(div). I cannot achieve this. I have attached a picture to explain what type of results I want to achieve.

Comment: Hi. You might want to [start here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) on how to ask questions on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Please could you post the HTML and CSS code that you're using?

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation bar */

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Style the "active" element to highlight the current page */

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}


/* Style the search box inside the navigation bar */

.topnav input[type=text] {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* When the screen is less than 600px wide, stack the links and the search field vertically instead of horizontally */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a,
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
</div>
```